# How to create a Button with custom Icons in Mapinfo 10?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am using mapinfo 10 and I have created dll with Pelles C with 16*16 and 24*24 bmp images. I placed the dll file into folder containing .mbx file but I get error :

> Unableable to locate external icon resource.

Am I missing something.

Code:

```
Create ButtonPad "mybuttonpad"  As
        ToggleButton
        ID 1001
        Icon 8001 File "icon.dll"
          Calling vendor_ButtonAction
          HelpMsg "ICONTEST"
Show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to try:

1.
 Add the full path to your icon.dll. I normally create a constant aóutside the main procedure and refer to this for all my buttons:

```
Define FILE_ICONS_DLL  ApplicationDirectory$() & "Icons.dll"

Sub Main
   Create ButtonPad "mybuttonpad"  As
        ToggleButton
        ID 1001
        Icon 8001 File FILE_ICONS_DLL
          Calling vendor_ButtonAction
          HelpMsg "ICONTEST"
```

2.
If that doesn't fix it, try to use lower numbers for you icons, for instance 1 (and 2). Also I assume that you added the small icons as no 8001 and the larger as no 8002. Right?

Comment: thanks for help but it now says could not convert data what might be the problem

Comment: convert the data? Can you be a bit more precise on the error message

Comment: When I add the code for DLL file it generates error "Cannot convert data" That's all.Is it problem with dll creating I have smaller icon with lower number.

Comment: Could you try with a different dll to see if it is the dll that is the problem. You can find some here: http://www.gispro.dk/php/download.php?rep=11&fil=DLLicons.zip

Comment: Actually a "+" in place of "&" in Define FILE_ICONS_DLL  ApplicationDirectory$() & "Icons.dll" solved problem.

Comment: That was strange. I always use & when combining strings! Anyway good that you found the problem

Comment: The &/+ thing has caught me out before. "+" for maths, "&" for everything else is the way to do it. The problem is that + works with strings *most* of the time, so when it doesn't it catches you out.

Comment: You might get into some trouble if you don't have spaces around your & as that might get confused with an hex number. Could that be the problem?